# Update Column 1 Based on time and repeating value in Column B

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, duplicates, sql-update

[image]
 Table A: ID (Identity) Name    State   StateTimestamp Course
              1             ABC      C      1/1/2001         ? 
              2             ABC      A      1/5/2001         OO 
              3             ABC      B      2/3/2001         OO 
              4             ABC      A      2/4/2001         PP 
              5             ABC      D      2/5/2001         PP 
              6             ABC      A      2/12/2001        QQ 
              7             ABC      A      2/18/2001        RR 
              8             ABC      z      2/20/2001        ? 
              9             XYZ      C      1/1/2001         ? 
             10             XYZ      A      1/14/2001        ? 
             11             XYZ      D      1/16/2001        ? 
             12             XYZ      A      1/17/2001        ? 
             13             XYZ      z      1/31/2001        ?

ID is a unique column. Each state belongs to name and has timestamp associated with it in an incremental order. 
 Update the course for each row based on the State-A, such that when state A occurs first time for a Name Update
 Course to 'OO', when state A occurs 2nd time for a Name update course 'PP' and When state C occurs 3rd time update
 course to 'QQ'. And the number of repeatation of State A can be infinite. 
 And Course for all of the states having date > State A and date < consequitive State A - i.e After 1 Pending state
 and before following pending state  (i.e B,2/3/2001 in the above table ) has to be updated same as the course for 
 precedding A state (i.e. OO). Your ideas will be much appreciated.

Create table As: 
 CREATE TABLE TABLEA
 (
   ID Identity 1,1
 , Name varchar(155)
 , State varchar(155)
 , StateTimestamp Datetime
 , Course varchar(155) 
 )

Populate As: 
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES
 ( 'ABC'    ,'C',   '1/1/2001'  , '? ')
,( 'ABC'    ,'A',   '1/5/2001'  , '?')
,( 'ABC'    ,'B',   '2/3/2001'  , '?')
,( 'ABC'    ,'A',   '2/4/2001'  , '?')
,( 'ABC'    ,'D',   '2/5/2001'  , '?')
,( 'ABC'    ,'A',   '2/12/2001' , '?')
,( 'ABC'    ,'A',   '2/18/2001' , '?')
,( 'ABC'    ,'z',   '2/20/2001' , '? ')
,( 'XYZ'    ,'C',   '1/1/2001'  , '? ')
,( 'XYZ'    ,'A',   '1/14/2001' , '? ')
,( 'XYZ'    ,'D',   '1/16/2001' , '? ')
,( 'XYZ'    ,'A',   '1/17/2001' , '? ')
,( 'XYZ'    ,'z',   '1/31/2001' , '? ')

Desired Result: 
 Table A: 
 ID (Identity)      Name          State    StateTimestamp       Course
 1                   ABC            C       1/1/2001            ?
 2                   ABC            A       1/5/2001            OO
 3                   ABC            B       2/3/2001            OO
 4                   ABC            A       2/4/2001            PP
 5                   ABC            D       2/5/2001            PP
 6                   ABC            A       2/12/2001           QQ
 7                   ABC            A       2/18/2001           RR
 8                   ABC            z       2/20/2001           RR
 9                   XYZ            C       1/1/2001            XX
 10                  XYZ            A       1/14/2001           YY
 11                  XYZ            D       1/16/2001           YY
 12                  XYZ            A       1/17/2001           ZZ
 13                  XYZ            z       1/31/2001           ZZ

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Table A:            
 ID (Identity)  Name     State     StateTimestamp     Course  
1   ABC   C  1/1/2001    ?
2   ABC   A  1/5/2001    OO
3   ABC   B  2/3/2001    OO
4   ABC   A  2/4/2001    PP
5   ABC   D  2/5/2001    PP
6   ABC   A  2/12/2001    QQ
7   ABC   A  2/18/2001    RR
8   ABC   z  2/20/2001    ?
9   XYZ   C  1/1/2001    ?
10   XYZ   A  1/14/2001    ?
11   XYZ   D  1/16/2001    ?
12   XYZ   A  1/17/2001    ?
13   XYZ   z  1/31/2001    ?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41868655/edit) your question to include the relevant table DDL, sample data as DML, desired results and your current attempt of getting them.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment?  What have you tried so far?